# Convert values in a list to RGB values

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, colors

I'm trying the following to convey the value in a list to a list of [R,G,B] values.

```
   data = range(0,6)
   minima = min(data)
   maxima = max(data)
   norm = matplotlib.colors.Normalize(vmin=minima, vmax=maxima, clip=True)
   mapper = cm.ScalarMappable(norm=norm, cmap=cm.Greys_r)
   node_color = []
   for d in data:
        node_color.append(mapper.to_rgba(d))
```

The above returns a 4th dimension A. I would like to know if there is a way to obtain only RGB values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mapper.to_rgba(d)` returns a tuple of the form `(r, g, b, a)`.  You can directly assign the result to a 4-tuple as `r, g, b, a = mapper.to_rgba(d)`. And then create a triple as `(r, g, b)` to be stored in a list.

[`mapper.to_rgba`](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.0/api/cm_api.html#matplotlib.cm.ScalarMappable.to_rgba) also works when it gets a list or array as parameter, so  calling `mapper.to_rgba(data)` directly gets the list of all rgba-tuples.  Via a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), a new list of rgb-triples can be created:

```py
import matplotlib
from matplotlib import cm

data = range(0, 6)
norm = matplotlib.colors.Normalize(vmin=min(data), vmax=max(data), clip=True)
mapper = cm.ScalarMappable(norm=norm, cmap=cm.Greys_r)
node_color = [(r, g, b) for r, g, b, a in mapper.to_rgba(data)]
```

PS: The above code gives r, g and b values between 0 and 1. Depending on the application, integer values from 0 to 255 could be needed:

```
node_color = [(r, g, b) for r, g, b, a in mapper.to_rgba(data, bytes=True)]
```